# export 'default' (imported as 'n') was not found in './n'

Tags: javascript, webpack

I want to include namespace of modules, and when I do it, it gives me warning, (and my code won't work), I'm importing my module like that

```
import * as agl from "./agl";
```

And using it like that:

```
var vbo = new agl.VertexBuffer();
```

My module just consists of including modules into single namespace:

```
import VertexArray from "./VertexArray";
import Display from "./Display";
import VertexBuffer from "./VertexBuffer";
import IndexBuffer from "./IndexBuffer"
import Shader from "./Shader";
import ShaderProgram from "./ShaderProgram";
import Texture from "./Texture";
import BufferLayout from "./BufferLayout";




export default {
  VertexArray,
  Display,
  VertexBuffer,
  IndexBuffer,
  Shader,
  ShaderProgram,
  Texture,
  BufferLayout
}
```

What could be the problem, and how can I import namespace of modules?

Answer (score 0):

**Default exports** should be imported this way:

```
import agl from "./agl";
```

Your code isn't working because you are trying to import all `the named exports`.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> export default {
>   VertexArray,
>   Display,
>   VertexBuffer,
>   IndexBuffer,
>   Shader,
>   ShaderProgram,
>   Texture,
>   BufferLayout
> }
> ```

This is horrible, and causing your problem. That module does default-export an object literal, instead of just using named exports. You should be using

```
export {
  VertexArray,
  Display,
  VertexBuffer,
  IndexBuffer,
  Shader,
  ShaderProgram,
  Texture,
  BufferLayout
}
```

instead to have your `import * as agl …` work.