# export default { foo, bar } doesn't work in node.js with babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I can't get export default { multiple, functions } to work.

Heres my setup:

`src/index.js`:

```
import {foo} from './foo'

foo();
```

`foo.js`:

```
const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}

export default {foo};
```

and my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "jestjs.io",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "babel-node src/index.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

when I run `npm start`, I get the following error message:

```
/src/index.js:5
(0, _foo.foo)();
         ^

TypeError: (0 , _foo.foo) is not a function
```

However, if I `export default foo` and `import foo` without the curly braces `{foo}`, it executes and I get `Hello!` printed to the terminal.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: How is the exporting module transpiled? The error lies there.

Comment: `import {foo}` will expect named `export const foo` or `export function foo`. With default export you need `import smth` and then use `smth.foo()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [export 'default' (imported as 'n') was not found in './n'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56256164/1048572)

Comment: Drop the `default` keyword and it will work (using named exports).

Answer (score 3):

You have used a default export and you try to access it using the named import syntax which is not possible, so you need first to import the default export:

```
import fooObj from '/.foo'; // {foo: f}
```

then you can access to your `foo` function:

```
fooObj.foo(); // Hello
```

Or you can use [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) if the object contains multiple properties:

```
import fooObj from '/.foo'; // {foo: f, bar: f}

const { foo, bar } = fooObj;

foo();
bar();
```

You can also export `foo` withtout `{}`:

```
const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}

export default foo;
```

Then import it like this:

```
import foo from './foo';

foo(); // Hello
```

Or you can use a named export:

```
export const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}
```

then:

```
import {foo} from './foo';

foo(); // Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting it like this:

```
const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}

export default foo;
```

This would make `foo` the default export from this file. If you want to export multiple files, you can do this.

```
export const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}

export const bar = () => {
    console.log("Hello!");
}
```

the difference is when importing, you can import the first one (default export) with any name, while the second has to be the exact name with which you exported it. 
e.g `import {foo, bar} from 'path/path'`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution I was looking for!

```
// foobar.js
const foo = () => {
    console.log("Hello FOO!");
}

const bar = () => {
    console.log("Hello BAR!");
}

export default {foo, bar}
```

//

```
index.js

import foobar from "./foobar"

const {foo, bar} = foobar

foo();
bar();
```

Thanks for all your help ! The other answers and comments made it clear to me what I was doing wrong.